# Bootstrap left collapsible navigation menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find a good template or portion code to apply the same menu I found in this website:

http://progressive.com/

I need the menu to show up from the left and the rest of the screen to go slightly darker, just like in the website I found.

Is there an easy way to apply a bootstrap template that does this? Or maybe is would be move convenient to start coding the navbar section from scratch?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo from [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation) might work for you. Adjusted example Snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
    overlay = $('.overlay'),
    isClosed = false;

  trigger.click(function() {
    hamburger_cross();
  });

  function hamburger_cross() {

    if (isClosed == true) {
      overlay.hide();
      trigger.removeClass('is-open');
      trigger.addClass('is-closed');
      isClosed = false;
    } else {
      overlay.show();
      trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
      trigger.addClass('is-open');
      isClosed = true;
    }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*           Wrappers            */

/*-------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 220px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 220px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -220px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 220px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -220px;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*     Sidebar nav styles        */

/*-------------------------------*/

.navbar .sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar .sidebar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar .sidebar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.navbar .sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.navbar .sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width .2s ease-in;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;
}
.navbar .sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
}
.navbar .sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar .sidebar-nav li a:active,
.navbar .sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.navbar .sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.navbar .sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.navbar .sidebar-nav li.open a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
.navbar .sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #222;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*       Hamburger-Cross         */

/*-------------------------------*/

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
  outline: none;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top {
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle {
  display: none;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73, 1, .28, .08);
}
.hamburger.is-open:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
/*-------------------------------*/

/*            Overlay            */

/*-------------------------------*/

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand"> <a href="#">
                       Brand
                    </a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">About</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Events</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Team</a>

      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Works <span class="caret"></span></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown heading</li>
          <li><a href="#">Action</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Services</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>

      </li>
      <li> <a href="https://twitter.com/maridlcrmn">Follow me</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas"> <span class="hamb-top"></span>
      <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
      <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>

    </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <h1>Fancy Toggle Sidebar Navigation</h1>

          <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet tri-tip shoulder tenderloin shankle. Bresaola tail pancetta ball tip doner meatloaf corned beef. Kevin pastrami tri-tip prosciutto ham hock pork belly bacon pork loin salami pork chop shank corned beef tenderloin meatball
            cow. Pork bresaola meatloaf tongue, landjaeger tail andouille strip steak tenderloin sausage chicken tri-tip. Pastrami tri-tip kielbasa sausage porchetta pig sirloin boudin rump meatball andouille chuck tenderloin biltong shank</p>
          <p>Pig meatloaf bresaola, spare ribs venison short loin rump pork loin drumstick jowl meatball brisket. Landjaeger chicken fatback pork loin doner sirloin cow short ribs hamburger shoulder salami pastrami. Pork swine beef ribs t-bone flank filet
            mignon, ground round tongue. Tri-tip cow turducken shank beef shoulder bresaola tongue flank leberkas ball tip.</p>
          <p>Filet mignon brisket pancetta fatback short ribs short loin prosciutto jowl turducken biltong kevin pork chop pork beef ribs bresaola. Tongue beef ribs pastrami boudin. Chicken bresaola kielbasa strip steak biltong. Corned beef pork loin cow
            pig short ribs boudin bacon pork belly chicken andouille. Filet mignon flank turkey tongue. Turkey ball tip kielbasa pastrami flank tri-tip t-bone kevin landjaeger capicola tail fatback pork loin beef jerky.</p>
          <p>Chicken ham hock shankle, strip steak ground round meatball pork belly jowl pancetta sausage spare ribs. Pork loin cow salami pork belly. Tri-tip pork loin sausage jerky prosciutto t-bone bresaola frankfurter sirloin pork chop ribeye corned
            beef chuck. Short loin hamburger tenderloin, landjaeger venison porchetta strip steak turducken pancetta beef cow leberkas sausage beef ribs. Shoulder ham jerky kielbasa. Pig doner short loin pork chop. Short ribs frankfurter rump meatloaf.</p>
          <p>Filet mignon biltong chuck pork belly, corned beef ground round ribeye short loin rump swine. Hamburger drumstick turkey, shank rump biltong pork loin jowl sausage chicken. Rump pork belly fatback ball tip swine doner pig. Salami jerky cow,
            boudin pork chop sausage tongue andouille turkey.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a jQuery plugin for the side menu?

http://www.berriart.com/sidr/ will meet your needs.

Making the rest of the screen go dark is a simple jQuery trick too. The SO answer below will help you with this.

[Jquery - dim entire page and fade up one div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913788/jquery-dim-entire-page-and-fade-up-one-div-element)

Answer (score 1):

I have just started something similar. I am not using an overlay to achieve the modal effect, but that should not be to hard to implement. Just take a look at the example and I am sure you will get the idea. Might be a good starting point, though the same thing can probably be achieved in many different ways.

```js
var $navbarToggle = $('.navbar-toggle'),
    $flyoutContainer = $('.navbar-flyout-container'),
    $flyoutDropdownItem = $('.flyout-dropdown-item');

function openFlyout (evt) {
  $(this).toggleClass('navbar-toggle-open');
  $flyoutContainer.toggleClass('navbar-flyout-open');
}

function openDropdownNavList (evt) {
  $(this).find('.flyout-dropdown-container').toggleClass('flyout-dropdown-open');    
}

$navbarToggle.on('click', openFlyout);

$flyoutDropdownItem.on('click', openDropdownNavList);
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

/*    Navbar Toggle Button
-----------------------------------------------------*/
.navbar-toggle {
  border-radius: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 8px 0 8px 15px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 44px;
  height: 34px;
  border-width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.21s ease-in;
  transition: margin 0.21s ease-in;
}

.navbar-toggle-open {
  margin: 8px 0 8px 261px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 8px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 26px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.15s ease;
  transition: top 0.15s ease;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar+.icon-bar {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-toggle > .icon-bar:nth-last-child(2) {
  top: 15px;
}

.navbar-toggle > .icon-bar:nth-last-child(3) {
  top: 21px;
}

/*    Navbar Toggle Button Hover
-----------------------------------------------------*/
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar:last-child {
  top: 7px;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar:nth-last-child(3) {
  top: 23px;
}

/*    Navbar Flyout
-----------------------------------------------------*/
.navbar-flyout-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -360px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 51px 0 25px; /* top padding height of .navbar-default and bottom-padding */
  background: gray;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-in;
}

.navbar-flyout-open {
  left: 0;
}

.navbar-flyout-container .navbar-flyout {
  width: 320px;
  max-width: 320px;
  height: inherit;
  padding-bottom: 64px; /* remove the height of .navbar-flyout-header from the bottom */    
}

.navbar-flyout .navbar-flyout-header {
  width: inherit;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-flyout .navlist {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.navbar-flyout .navlist li {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.navbar-flyout .navlist li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.navbar-flyout .navlist li a {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 6px;
}

.navbar-flyout .navlist li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*    Flyout Dropdown
-----------------------------------------------------*/

.flyout-dropdown-container {
  max-height: 0;
  width: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.85s ease-out;    
  transition: max-height 0.85s ease-out;
}

.flyout-dropdown-open {
  max-height: 1000px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.85s ease-in;
  transition: max-height 0.85s ease-in;
}

.flyout-dropdown-container .navlist-dropdown {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.flyout-dropdown-container .navlist-dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom-width: 0; 
}


/*    Responsive Behaviour
-----------------------------------------------------*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* keep negative margin */
  .container-fluid > .navbar-header {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }

  /* always show navbar-toggle */
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;     
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Flyout Navbar -->
<div class="navbar-flyout-container">
  <div class="navbar-flyout">
    <div class="navbar-flyout-header">

    </div>
    <ul class="navlist">
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li><a href="#">very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong item 2</a></li>
      <li class="flyout-dropdown-item">Dropdown
        <div class="flyout-dropdown-container">
          <ul class="navlist-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">very looooooooooooooooooooooooooong dropdown item 1</a></li>
            <li>dropdown item 2</li>
            <li>dropdown item 3</li>
            <li>dropdown item 4</li>
            <li>dropdown item 5</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>item 4</li>
      <li>item 5</li>
      <li>item 6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Flyout Navbar -->
```